# undefined reference to function in main()

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference

i tried to make a program on seperate files. Unfortunatelty i had erros while trying to build the code. It was pointing on undefined references to constuctors,destructos and function CzynnikiPierwsze. So i decied to put the whole code in one code. Still there is a problem in main() function: undefined reference to 'CzynnikiPierwsze(int)' Any ideas whats wrong? Here is the whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
vector<int> CzynnikiPierwsze(int);


class NieprawidlowaDana                           //wyjatki
    {};
class SpozaZakresu
    {};



class RozkladLiczby{
    private:
        int *tab;
    public:
        RozkladLiczby(int);                  //konstruktor
        vector<int> CzynnikiPierwsze(int); //metoda
        ~RozkladLiczby();
};
```

/////////////////BODY of the CLASS/////////////////////////////////////

```
RozkladLiczby::~RozkladLiczby()         //destruktor
{}

RozkladLiczby::RozkladLiczby(int n){
    int* tab = new int[n+1];
    int i,j;

    for( i=0;i<=n;i++)
        tab[i]=0;                  //zerujemy tablice

    for( i=2;i<=n;i+=2)
        tab[i]=2;                  //zajmujemy sie liczbami parzystymi

    for(i=3; i<=n;i+=2)
        for(j=i;j<=n;j+=i)         //sito erastotesa
            if(tab[j]==0)
                tab[j]=i;


}

   vector<int> RozkladLiczby::CzynnikiPierwsze(int m){
        vector<int> tablica;
        while(m!=1){
            tablica.push_back(tab[m]);
            m=m/tab[m];
        }

return tablica;

}


////////////////////////END OF THE BODY//////////////////////////////




int parsuj(char* argz){
    int i=0;
        while(argz[i] != '\0'){                  //funckja ktora konwertuje na int i sprawdza czy wprowadzaony zostal string
            if( !isdigit(argz[i]))
                throw NieprawidlowaDana();
                i=i+1;
            }
        int x = stoi(argz);
        if (x >= 2)
            return x;
        else
            throw SpozaZakresu();

}






//////////////////GLOWNY BLOK///////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){


    vector<int> tablica,p;
    int i,n;
    int max;

     for( i=1;i<=argc-1;i++){
        n = parsuj(argv[i]);
        tablica.push_back(n);
    }

     max=tablica[0];

     for(i=1; i<=argc-1;i++){
        if(tablica[i]>max)
            max=tablica[i]; }  // sprawdzamy max 

    RozkladLiczby odp = RozkladLiczby(max);  //utwoorzylismy obiekt z maxa


     for(unsigned int i=0;i<=tablica.size()-1;i++){
        p=CzynnikiPierwsze(tablica[i]);
        cout<<tablica[i]<<" = ";
        int x= p[0];

        int licznik = 1;
        for(unsigned int j=1;j<=p.size()-1;j++){
            if(x==p[j])
                licznik++;
            else if(licznik!=1)
                cout<<x<<"^"<<licznik<<"*";
            else
                cout<<x<<"*";
        } 
            cout<<endl;

        }

return 0;

}
```

I would be grateful if u could solve this.

Comment: `p=CzynnikiPierwsze(tablica[i]);` is perhaps intended to be `p=odp.CzynnikiPierwsze(tablica[i]);`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have declared global function `vector<int> CzynnikiPierwsze(int);` but you have not defined it anywhere in your program. In your main you are calling global function and not the one which is your class member.

Comment: He's defined it as a class function.

Comment: i am dumb. THats true.  I should use odp.CzynnikiPierwsze() to get to this function. Ty

Comment: That is class member not the global function.